# What's the use of "favourite this question"?

Tags: support, bookmarks

In general, if a question helps me in some way on Stack Overflow, or if I think it is a good question I give it an upvote. Which brings me to my question or need of some sort. The OP asks a question and I like it plus I think that this question might help me as well, so I add it to my favourite list.

Now the question has no answers and I want to be informed if a new answer kicks in. How do I do that? Why does making a question starred not keep me notified and also shouldn't the answer have a **star** option? Because most of the time I might just like the answer, not the question?

Comment: Your favourites tab will be highlighted when an answer comes in.

Comment: I think that highlight only shows news question that I starred, am i wrong?

Comment: It shows any update to a question you starred, including updates to the answers on that page and comments added to either the question or to any answers.

Comment: What @Martijn said plus when you have 10k on the site the question stays in your favorites even when deleted (then it gets a red background), so easily found.

Comment: Great, all this time I wondered why favourite question tab stayed highlighted always, thanks guys

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Starring a question means you get notified of *any update* on the question *page*.

This includes new answers, edits to any answer or the question, and new comments on either the questions or on an answer.

That means that when your question receives its first answer, your favourites tab in your profile will be highlighted (the number indicates the number of new or updated 'items').

Comment: Is there any limit in number of favorite questions? I have tried to favorite this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20663076/angularjs-app-run-documentation 
it doesn't show start or upvotes highlighted when I refresh the page. Also, upvoting answer shows **You last voted on this answer 1 hour ago. Your vote is now locked in unless this answer is edited.**

Comment: May be that was an temporary error, seems working now. First part still stands, **Is there any limit in number of favorite questions?**

Comment: There is no limit in the number of favorite questions.

Comment: Is there any opportunity to receive notifications on this question, not just highlight it?

Comment: *"means you get notified of any update on the question page."* ... this is not notification, I have to be on the profile page and check every minute for updates, is there any way to get these notifications as notification messages ?

Comment: @Accountantم: no, not as inbox messages, no. For a specific tag you can use an RSS reader to be notified of new posts; there is a *feed* icon in the bottom right for that. The same for individual questions.

Comment: It also means your favorites tab will randomly highlight with activity even when there is no activity...

Answer (score 7):

In case anyone missed it, Stack Overflow now has the "follow" feature, which is better than bookmarking a question if you want to see future activity. See my answer to [How can we "follow" everything about a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291468/how-can-we-follow-everything-about-a-question)