# Show what activity triggers favorites tab counters

Tags: feature-request, bookmarks

It seems to me from my own personal confusion and from questions like [How to find out what activity activated a favorite](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/2039/how-to-find-out-what-activity-activated-a-favorite) and [What's the use of "favorite this question"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252515) that figuring out exactly what causes the activity indicator on the favorites tab (i.e. *what* has changed on *which* question) often requires a bit of detective work.

Can we have a feature that says precisely what has changed against questions with activity. i.e. "New answer added", "Comment posted" or "Question deleted" etc. so as to avoid wasting time figuring out what has occurred?

As @MartijnPieters points out in comments, this has come up elsewhere too:

- [Can't favorites work more like the activity and reputation tabs?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/110833)
- [Detail Recent Favorite changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/83292)

Comment: Meta.SE related: [Can't favorites work more like the activity and reputation tabs?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/110833) and [Detail Recent Favorite changes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/83292)

Comment: @MartijnPieters So now you've just basically done this twice to me in as many minutes... why no "close as duplicate" :) ? Shouldn't I delete this?

Comment: Because the other posts are on a different site I can't close this as a duplicate. It's fine to have a similar discussion here, just wanted to point out that Meta.SE already has discussions on the topic if you wanted to chime in there.

Comment: Cheers. I have put my votes in... :)

Comment: @MartijnPieters I was about to write a similar question. What happened to this topic? Seems like it's been discussed for 4-8 years now. The votes show that it is well received. Should I write a new question?

Comment: @jay.sf: see [How to renew an old feature request?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/364131) for advice on how to bring attention to a feature request you want to see implemented.