# Favourite tab badge appears even if there is no new favourite items

Tags: support, bookmarks

I can see favourite tab badge almost every time I visit my profile page. But I haven't added any questions to favourites in a while.

[image]

**Edit**

The tooltip only shows "The question you have favourited". So obviously the user will think that new question got added to favourites.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/286923/476

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The counter indicates *new activity* in posts you have favourited; not the number of new favourites.