# How can I get notifications when a question is updated?

Tags: support, feature-request, edits, notifications

A few times a question has piqued my interest, and I would like to answer it, but I have to wait for the asker to update some details, or make it a mcve. How can I get notified (other than posing a comment asking the OP to mention me in yet another comment) when they make changes to the question?

If there isn't a way, this is a feature request..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that the current way is not immediately [obvious](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252512/whats-the-use-of-favourite-this-question).

> Starring a question means you get notified of any update on the
>   question page.

I'd suggest that we change the little [image: star icon] to a [little bell](https://icomoon.io/app/#/select), or may be a [pair of glasses](http://www.gettyimages.com/detail/illustration/royalty-free-vector-icon-button-with-pair-of-royalty-free-illustration/469020094), and say on the mouseover:

> [image: little bell icon]  Notify me when this page changes (click again to undo)

*[square vector graphic of the little bell found on [icomoon.io](https://icomoon.io/app/#/select) in the [IcoMoon - Free](https://icomoon.io/#icons-icomoon) Collection]*

And change the tab `favorites` on our profile page from

[image: tab bar from user profile showing favorites tab]

to `notify me` or `subscribed`

Comment: Ah I see, thanks. Thought it simply bookmarked the question for later.