# Can I save Stack Overflow questions to my profile?

Tags: discussion, questions, bookmarks

Is it possible to mark/save/attach some of the questions you feel important 
that after some you can refer back directly from your profile?

Comment: You have a star under the voting arrows. Look at your favorites tab.

Comment: What is *"stack trace"*?

Comment: @Jonrsharpe Sorry i wrongly mentioned the `Stack Over Flow` as `StackTrace`

Comment: @CodeCaster:  That describes *what* it does, not *how* it's done.

Comment: @Makoto yeah maybe that was a bit tongue-in-cheek, but I'm sure there is at least a handful of real duplicates. Can't find them though.

Comment: @CodeCaster:  At least wait until you have a *suitable* dupe...I could agree that this has been answered half a dozen times, but I'm not for just closing it under *some* dupe because it's tangentially related.

Comment: @Makoto well that's what I still consider duplicates useful for. I don't do it like that on main because it's frowned upon, but it just skips a step or an intermediate question. For example in [your answer here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/309166/266143), you basically paraphrase the [answer of the duplicate](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252515/266143). And ironically, OP just accepted it as helpful. Anyway, cross-site duplicate: [Save or Bookmark favorite questions in Stack Overflow \[duplicate\]](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68449/)

Answer (score 1):

This is what the [Favorites tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2477031/deepak-sai?tab=favorites) is for in your profile.  You can mark a question as a favorite by clicking on the gray star underneath its vote count.  Once you favorite it, the star will turn yellow and be available to you in that tab.