# Different types of favorites and favorite search

Tags: discussion, feature-request

**Summary - TLDR**

Would it be useful to have different types or categories of favorites?

**Explanation**

-Let's say I'm following my liked tags and I'm waiting for 3 or so questions to have any updates. Even though I might keep tabs open, I also like to add some questions to favorites, maybe because I just want to **know how the answer turned out** or because I would like to **help if there is** any **new information**.

-But there is also **another type of question** that I like to favorite, the ones that might **help** me **answer and back other answers or suggestions**, such as [How can I prevent SQL-injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/4577762) **-** [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/4577762) and so on. Some of them are protected, some are not. Some are not as popular as these, so it might be hard to re-find without favorite.

But here is the thing, the favorites are used to check for updates on questions. From [What's the use of “favourite this question”](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252512/4577762)'s answer:

> Starring a question means you get notified of any update on the
>   question page.

This tells me that I'm kinda using it wrong for the second topic, since I'm not really expecting it to have any updates. I would like just to save these VIQs *(not VIP xD)* and be able to separate them from the usual ones.

Note that the already implemented ordering (`added` - `views` - `newest` - `activity` - `votes`) aren't really usefull for this purpuse.

Comment: Your browser does bookmarks, right?

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå, my research has failed me. And I looked over and over for this. THX!

Comment: @jonrsharpe, You know there is a polite way to say that, right ^^? Besides, bookmarking on my browser wouldn't' itself allow me to see them from anywhere with internet access.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: browser do not share links between devices

Comment: @EugenKonkov that's not necessarily true. I know Firefox and chrome both do.