# How do I find where I was?

Tags: support, questions

After a lot of searching concerning getting/setting permissions in FireMonkey, I found a most helpful file buried down in the depths somewhere which gave me a .zip file with FMX.Permissions.Android.pas.  This has been most helpful, but required an addition to make it work properly (specifically adding a definition for tMessageResultPermissions).

I cannot find the link again to pass this on to the writer.  Is there any way of finding your history in Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 7):

Your browser history is probably your only real option, since that's used to tracking your movements between different web pages.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Makoto that you have to rely on your browser history here, but note that it is possible to bookmark questions through the ["favorite" star button](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252512/8528014) below the voting panel. The questions will then appear in your profile. This feature will be [renamed to "bookmark"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345148) in the near future.

I use this for quickly one-click storing questions I'm frequently interested in, and avoid cluttering my browser with tons of short-lived bookmarks. However, as pointed out by Makyen in the comments, the "favorite" functionality by SO only provides a flat list with limited sorting options, while your browser might offer advanced functionality like grouping/tagging/searching bookmarks.

Comment: Clutter in your browser's bookmarks can be controlled by using folders to organize bookmarks by whatever criteria you desire. Depending on the browser, your bookmarks may also have the ability to be "tagged". If you really have a lot of posts you want to know how to get back to, I find actual bookmarks to be significantly more flexible than the current flat "favorites" list on each SE site. People tend to use tools such as browsers in the way they are comfortable. Thus, what works for one person may not be preferred by another. Providing a list of options is probably better.

Comment: @Makyen Yeah, I agree that this depends on ones individual preferred workflow. I only have few posts in my favorite list (which often change depending on my current projects and interests), so the flat list does not pose such of a problem. Nevertheless, I just wanted to point out that this feature exists, and not give any recommendation :)